# Simultaneously testing (referencing) more than one cell in the same range while using an array formula

Tags: reference, array-formulas, openoffice-calc

I'm trying to create an array formula, part of which will return TRUE if two DIFFERENT cells in the SAME range simultaneously satisfy two different conditional tests. I will explain:

I want to build a spreadsheet to keep track of work dates, times, and pay. I have a column for dates, a column for hours worked, and a column for pay rate (I do not earn the same pay rate for all the hours I work). For a given pay period, I want to add up all the hours worked at a given pay rate.

Sometimes I work more than one job in the same day, and on those occasions I enter the date on the first row I'm using for that date, but on the next row (for the second job on the same date) I leave the "date" cell blank. If I had dates in BOTH of these cells in the date column, I could get the total I want using:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Sheet1.$D$1:Sheet1.$D$n>=$Sx; Sheet1.$D$1:Sheet1.$D$n<=$Ex; Sheet1.$R$1:Sheet1.$R$n=dd.dd; Sheet1.$H$1:Sheet1.$H$n)
```

(...where "D" is the column of dates (on Sheet1, a range of rows 1 through n), "Sx" is the cell with the pay period starting date, "Ex" is the cell with the pay period ending date, "R" is the column showing pay rate, "dd.dd" is the given pay rate I'm using as part of my search criteria (an actual number, in the actual formula), and "H" is the column showing hours worked.)

Obviously, I could just fill in dates in all the cells in "D" and use the above formula, but having a blank cell where I work two jobs in the same day makes it easier, visually, to pick out those days, so I'm hoping I can come up with a formula that basically says "if the date cell being tested (call it "Dx") is BLANK, AND the PREVIOUS date cell (that is, "D[x-1]") meets the above search criteria (i.e. is within the given pay period), then return TRUE (i.e. 1)", so that (presuming the pay rate also matches) the hours from that row would be included in the final total.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why to complicate things, just fill out all dates and have a conditional format to make the font color white if the value of the cell is equal to the cell above. You don't really need the cell to be empty nor blank, as per your explanation just need it be "look" empty that's achieved with conditional format...

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found the answer to my own question -- it seems that I can test for BOTH a blank cell AND a (criterion-matching) immediately preceding cell in the same array formula by using a range for the second test that begins and ends one cell previous to the range used in the first test. For example:

=SUMPRODUCT(Sheet1.$D$3:Sheet1.$D$300=0; Sheet1.$D$2:Sheet1.$D$299>=$Sx; ...etc.

As far as I can tell, this seems to work. The idea to try this just popped into my head this morning after sleeping on the problem...